# jdeprscan throws cannot find class error

Tags: java, java-9, jdeprscan

I'm trying `jdeprscan` on my CentOS system. Here are the commands that I'm executing:

```
export classpath=<PATH/*>:<ANOTHER/PATH/*>:<SOME/OTHER/PATH/*>
jdeprscan --for-removal --verbose --class-path $classpath --release 9 <ANOTHER/PATH>/MyProject.jar
```

In spite of providing the classpath, I'm getting multiple errors of this sort

```
Processing class <some/class/in/MyProject.jar>...
error: cannot find class <some/class/in/a/different/jar>
error: cannot resolve Methodref <some/class/in/a/different/jar>.<method>:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I've verified that the class mentioned in the error message are pretty much among one of the jars provided in the classpath.
Strangely, it's not the case that I'm getting this error for every other classes referred in the jar that I'm scanning.

Few points for your consideration:

- The are 50+ jars in the paths provided in the classpath
- The jar that  I'm trying to scan is residing in one of the paths  mentioned in the classpath
- I've tried jdeprscan available in JDK 9 & JDK 10 and getting the same errors
- I've tried replacing the * in classpath with ***.jar**, doesn't help!

Is there anything wrong in the syntax that I'm following or is this a known bug in jdeprscan?

Comment: Please ensure that *To scan a JAR file or a set of class files, you must first ensure that all of the classes that the scanned classes depend upon are present in the classpath.* This can be confirmed as *Typically, you would use the same classpath as the one that you use when invoking your application.*

Comment: Agree, I've taken care of it. I even went ahead and extracted the jar to check whether the class file exists in it, and it does!

Comment: Try listing the jars explicitly instead of using wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

Some preliminary notes on `jdeprscsan` from Oracle JDK 11 under Windows (I know the question related to JDK 9 on CentOS, but maybe the following applies as well...):

- use wildcard "path/to/lib/*.jar" (it will not work without the ".jar" extension)
- having a wildcard with more than one path is not supported (i.e. `--class-path dir1/;dir2/*.jar` throws a parse exception on the wildcard)
- JARs in the directory specified by `--class-path` are added to the classpath and analyzed in alphabetical order, which may cause some `error : cannot find class X` messages because a JAR `a.jar` may depend on a JAR `b.jar` which is not yet loaded.

Based on the above, I found the 3 solutions below. Note that I did the same experiment with `jdeprscan` from the Oracle JDK 12.0.2 without any improvement.

### Solution 1: all classes on the classpath

1. unzip all JARs in a specific directory (ignore overwritted files such as META-INF/maven/pom.xml), e.g. `mylib` (note that at this stage, the mylibs directory contains only classes organized by directory packages, and no JARs).
2. run the following command:

`jdeprscan --for-removal --class-path /path/to/mylib /path/to/my-application.jar`

**Advantage**: fast (very manual operations)

**Drawback**: only analyses the JAR file that has been specified on the command line (`my-application.jar`)

### Solution 2: all JARs + a fat JAR on the classpath

1. copy all JARs libs into a single `mylib` directory
2. extract all files from JARs of `mylib` (ignore duplicate files) and repack them into a big JAR `mylib/00lib.jar` (a simple ZIP file renamed to `.jar` makes the trick)
3. copy the `mylib/00lib.jar` to `mylib/01lib.jar` to ensure that it will be analysed
4. run the following command:

   `jdeprscan --for-removal --verbose --class-path path/to/mylib/*.jar path/to/my-application.jar`

**Advantage**: fast (only a few manual operations) + analyses the JARs from `mylib`

**Drawback**: some of the `jdeprscan` messages will be related to the fat JAR `00lib.jar` so you will not be able to determine immediately which library uses classes that are deprecated or removed from Java 9 or 11, but you can do it indirectly by looking at the class name, e.g. (a class from the `com.atomikos` library requires the missing class `javax.jms.JMSException`):

```
Processing class com/atomikos/datasource/xa/jms/JmsTransactionalResource...
error: cannot find class javax/jms/JMSException
```

### Solution 3: reorder the JAR files on the classpath

1. copy all JARs libs into a single `mylib` directory
2. run the following command:

   `jdeprscan --for-removal --class-path path/to/mylib/*.jar path/to/my-application.jar`
3. inspect the log to see `error: cannot find class` messages that are not supposed to be raised because the JAR exists in the lib directory. For each such library, copy the library with a name that is before the library name which reference it alphabetically speaking. For example, I have a JAR in the lib dir `alpha.jar` which depends on `commons-lang-3.0.jar` (which is not yet loaded in the classpath), so I copy `commons-lang-3.0.jar` to `a0commons-lang-3.0.jar` so that it will be loaded before `alpha.jar`. It is important to copy the JAR and not to rename it otherwise it may not be analyzed by `jdeprscan` (does not occur on every JAR). Once done, go back to step 2 until no error messages produced by library dependencies occurs.

**Advantage**: gives a clear view of which JAR uses deprecated/removed classes.

**Drawback**: takes a lot time (manual copy of each individual JARs which cause a classloading issue).

### Conclusion

I use `jdeprscan` with **Solution 2**. This should be considered as a workaround (is it an incomplete tool documentation or a bug, I don't know...).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a folder in PATH which has classes **and** JARs, it won't work. You'd have to specify the JARs individually (or get rid of the classes).