# How to run `jdeprscan` on an EAR

Tags: java, java-9, ear, jdeprscan

The [`jdeprscan`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeprscan.html) tool determines lists all deprecated and non-existing dependencies. It can run on classes, directories and on a JAR.

But how to run it on an EAR ?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217414/698168, I explode the EAR into JARs using the following script (Windows) :

```
rem remove previous run
rd /s /q ear

rem extract the EAR
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -oear *.ear

rem extract the WAR
cd ear
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -owar *.war

rem unify JAR from EAR and WAR
copy war\WEB-INF\lib\*.jar lib

rem make JAR with the classes
cd war\WEB-INF\classes
rem "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r my-app.jar
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\jar" cvf my-app.jar -C . .
rem Note: using 7zip to create the JAR may lead to errors when running jdeprscan, thus we are using the jar command
copy my-app.jar ..\..\..

rem return to origin
cd ..\..\..

rem unpack all libraries...
cd lib
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x  -aoa -oclasses *.jar

rem .. and repack them as a fat JAR
cd classes
rem "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r 00lib.jar
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\jar" cvf 00lib.jar -C . .

rem duplicate the fat JAR and make some cleaning
copy 00lib.jar ..\00lib.jar
copy 00lib.jar ..\01lib.jar
cd ..
rd /s /q classes

rem return to origin
cd ..\..
```

Note that this script does not use the librairies from the JEE Server (i.e. all the Maven librairies with scope "provided" will be reported as `error: cannot find class` by `jdeprscan`).

Then I generate a `jdeprscan` report using the following command :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\jdeprscan" --for-removal --verbose --class-path ear\lib\*.jar ear\my-app.jar > deprscan.log 2>&1
```

You can then inspect the `jdeprscan.log` file. The classes that are not found may not exist in the newest Java version (such as 11) or may be present in the JEE modules. A missing class looks like the following (`BASE64Encoder` is not provided anymore by Java 11 but is used by `ChecksumHelper`):

```
Processing class oracle/spatial/security/ChecksumHelper...
error: cannot find class sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
```

In the best case, you can find the JAR name above in the log file (e.g. `Jar file my-lib-2.3.4.jar`), otherwise you will need to determine the library from the class name.

Note: all the above was designed with the idea to migrate Java 8 to Java 11.

Comment: This is awesome! I removed the "Processing class..." messages using Regex Replace on Notepad++ which ended up giving a neat report of all the discontinued classes.

Comment: I faced one minor issue where I was using signed JARs in my EAR. Hence the signature validation was throwing errors when running the ```jdeprscan``` tool. I had to manually delete the *.RSA and MANIFEST.* from 00lib.jar to get it working.